# Prove $A+B= A \cup B$ if and only if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ using the definition of $A+B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Define the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$, written $A+B$, by $A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$.

Prove $A+B= A \cup B$ if and only if $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

My attempt:

Part 1b. If $A+B = A \cup B$, then $ A \cap B = \emptyset$

$A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$.

There shouldn't be any elements inside $A \cap B$.

$A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (\emptyset)$

Therefore, $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Edit: What if I put...

Definition: Let $(A \cup B)$ and $(A \cap B)$ be sets. The complement of $(A \cup B)$ relative to $(A \cap B)$, written $ (A \cup B)\backslash (A \cap B)$ is the set $(A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B) = [x: x \in (A \cup B) \land x \notin (A \cap B)]$

While the elements are inside $(A \cup B)$, they don't belong in $(A \cap B)$

hmmmm they isn't any element in common...so it's an emptyset... wait a sec... emptyset means that there aren't any elements.

Part 2b. If $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then $A+B = A \cup B$

$A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (\emptyset)$

Definition: Let $(A \cup B)$ and $\emptyset$ be sets. The complement of $(A \cup B)$ relative to $\emptyset$, written $ (A \cup B)\backslash \emptyset$ is the set $(A \cup B) \backslash \emptyset = [x: x \in (A \cup B) \land x \notin \emptyset]$

There are elements inside $A \cup B$, but not in $A \cap B$.

As a result, $A+B = (A \cup B)$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: To prove sets $C,D$ are equal, you need to show that each element of $C$ is an element of $D$, and vice-versa.

Comment: huh? well... this is a biconditional statement right? I did split them up into two parts .

Comment: Yes, that's true, but within each part you are claiming that certain sets are equal to others.  For example, to prove that $(A\cup B)\setminus \emptyset=(A\cup B)$ you said some things, but you did not prove that the two sets are equal.

Comment: You need to add more details to part1, you didn't prove anything. As for part2, your idea is correct but you need to formalize/write it better.

Comment: hmm so how do I prove that they're equal? Like... $A+B=(A \cup B) \backslash (\emptyset)$.... use the definition? Definition: Let (A∪B) and ∅ be sets. The complement of (A∪B) relative to ∅, written (A∪B)∖∅ is the set (A∪B)∖∅=[x:x∈(A∪B)∧x∉∅]... there are no elements in $A \cap B$ since there are elements in the $A \cup B$

Comment: @dani_s I'm new at proof writing...and yeah I do need more details for part one. I just jumped to a conclusion. I should've included a definition.

Comment: @usukidoll note that $x \notin \emptyset$ is true by definition of empty set, therefore $x \in A \cup B \land x \notin \emptyset$ is equivalent to $x \in A \cup B$, i.e. $(A \cup B) \setminus \emptyset = A \cup B$

Comment: @dani_s I've edited my post and included some things in part one...but I just don't know how to conclude it... If x doesn't belong to $A \cap B$, then?!!!

Comment: @usukidoll try a proof by contradiction: suppose there exists $x \in A \cap B$, then prove that $x \notin A + B$ but $x \in A \cup B$, which would imply that $A + B$ and $A \cup B$ cannot be equal. (More technically you would be proving the contrapositive.)

Comment: alright so if there were elements inside $A \cap B$, then there can't be any elements at all in $A+B$, yet x belongs to $A \cup B$.. So.... hmmm....argh some statements are easier to prove than others ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to show you the result exploiting the definitions.

Define the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$ (written $A+B$), by

> $A+B = (A \cup B) \backslash (A \cap B)$.

We have that

> $x \in A+B \quad$ iff $\quad ( x \in A \lor x \in B) \quad$ **and** $\quad \lnot (x \in A \land x \in B)$

But we have also that

> $x \in A \cup B \quad$ iff $\quad ( x \in A \lor x \in B)$

Now we want that $A + B$ must be equal to $A \cup B$.

If we "compare" the two above condition, we can write them as

> $P \land Q$ and $P$, and we want that $P \land Q \equiv P$.

By truth-table, we can check that $P \land Q \equiv P$ iff $Q$ is identically *true*.

So, we want that our condition $\lnot (x \in A \land x \in B)$ must be identically *true*.

This is simply :

> $\forall x \lnot (x \in A \land x \in B)$.

By definition, $x \in A \cap B$ iff $x \in A \land x \in B$.

So, our condition is : $\forall x (x \notin A \cap B)$ and this, in turn, means that $A \cap B$ is $\emptyset$ (the *empty set*).

Comment: thanks. this is the approach that I wanted to go...not by contradiction because I got lost further than when I was trying to prove the actual statement.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, think at my suggestions : *(i)* use the definitions; *(ii)* progress step-by-step; *(iii)* for me, there is no magic in *proof by contradiction*: use it only when you do not have any other resource.

Answer (score 0):

A + B := A\B U B\A. We will use this definition to prove the claim and it is equivalent to the definition given in the statement above. 
===> If A + B = A U B. Then we show the intersection of A and B to be empty. If this is not true then there is a y in A and B. So y in A U B and therefore y in A + B. So that means y is in A\B or B\A. But neither of these can happen since y is in both sets A and B. Thus we obtain a contradiction. So the intersection of A and B is empty. 
<=== If A intersects B is empty. We show A + B = A U B. We have A U B = A\B U B\A U C,
where C is the intersection of A and B. So if C = empty set, then A U B = A\B U B\A = A + B